# Unable to scrape promotion price details from website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape promotion price details from: https://www.fairprice.com.sg/product/magnolia-fresh-milk-1lt-13022014

Specifically, I'm trying to scrape the "Any 2 for $5.45, Save $1.55" bit of information. When I run the code below, it gives me a null return.

Using the same code on other products in the same website works though (e.g.  https://www.fairprice.com.sg/product/kirei-kirei-hand-soap-rfl-moisturing-peach-200ml-12089153 )

Unsure what is causing the difference in behavior. Appreciate any advise on this issue.

```
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
    
try:
    url = 'https://www.fairprice.com.sg/product/magnolia-fresh-milk-1lt-13022014'
    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.69'}
    page=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
except Exception as e:
    error_type, error_obj, error_info = sys.exc_info()
    print ('ERROR FOR LINK:', url)
    print (error_type, 'Line:', error_info.tb_lineno)
    
time.sleep(2)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
linkpromo=soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'sc-1bsd7ul-1 eSToaS'},string=re.compile(r'Any'))   

print(linkpromo)
```

Comment: what you are looking for isn't actually loaded on the page. If you print your soup object before you try to find the info you want you will not see It as part of the span as what you see on your browser. But you can see that information in the final script tag on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically so the data you are looking for is not in the html returned. You can use [`requests-html`](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) package to render the page. See below sample

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession   

url = 'https://www.fairprice.com.sg/product/magnolia-fresh-milk-1lt-13022014'
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render(timeout=20)

linkpromo=r.html.xpath("//div[@data-testid='offer-details'][last()]/div/span/text()")

print(linkpromo)
```

You will get below output in the terminal:

```sh
['Any 2 for $5.45, Save $1.55']
```

Comment: I'm trying to extract the price "S3.50" and product name "F&N Magnolia Fresh Milk" from the same page. What should the correct xpath link be? When i try to provide the full xpath link obtained from Developer Tools, it doesn't work.

Comment: The data is contained in a script tag in the html. What you see on the page is loaded via javascript. To obtain the name and price you can parse the text in the script tag and then parse it as json. See a sample of what you can do from this [link](https://pastebin.com/p8YEdpHL). The `json_data` object contains all the information you might need.

Comment: The code to scrape Javascript contents from the link appears to work for that particular product. When I apply it on a different product ( e.g. https://www.fairprice.com.sg/product/zespri-new-zealand-kiwifruit-green-4-6-per-pack-13045571 ) , it doesn't seem to work. Trying to get the name "Zespri New Zealand Kiwifruit - Green"